# I'm using a build pipeline job with parameters to call a downstream job in Jenkins; how do I print the main job name in the post block?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using a build pipeline job with parameters to call a downstream job in Jenkins; how do I print the job name in the post block?
I know how to print the job name if the downstream job is executed, but how do I print the build job name that is triggering the downstream job in post block?

Answer (score 0):

In downstream job, you can use:

```
    def upstreamCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)
    if (upstreamCause) {
        // search for name, build number, etc. in upstreamCause object
    }
```

The Javadoc for `UpstreamCause` class is [here](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UpstreamCause.html).

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer and assistance. I added in post block and it's working.